# Cracks in my Subfloor

Tags: subfloor

I recently had some water leak in my second floor condo. I had a water mitigation team come out and assess damage, luckily there was none. However, when they pulled up the flooring, I noticed theses cracks in my floor, which gave me immediate worry. Is this an indication of foundation problems?
[image]ow would someone remediate this these types of cracks?

Comment: Do not think that is the actual floor(base).  Might be some type of self levelling compound/cement(covering the base structure) to make sure the floor is level/flat for the finish flooring.

Comment: That certainly does indicate movement (which may not be a problem), but we'd need to know more about what that is. How thick is it? What's underneath?

Comment: It looks like mosaic tiles floor, not cracks

Comment: Yes, its a bit of an odd pattern... Tbh I am not sure how thick it is . I purchased this unit back in June. The place was built in 1972.

Comment: I'd chip up a little area and see if it delineates into two disparate materials.  I guess SLC that then had a load put on it maybe before it had reached full strength.